# Truth Table problems

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

**The problem**:

> > You are walking in a labyrinth, which contains at its center a vast treasure. Suddenly, you find yourself in front of three possible paths: a gold path to your left, a marble path in the middle, and a stone path to your right. Each path is protected by a centaur, and they tell you the following: The centaur of the gold path says, “This path will bring you straight to the center. Moreover, if the stone path takes you to the center, then so will the marble path.” The centaur of the marble path says, "Neither the gold path nor the stone path will take you to the center." The centaur of the stone path says, "Follow the gold path and you’ll reach the center, follow the marble path and you will be lost." You were warned ahead of time that all three centaurs are liars.
>
> 1. Consider three propositions $g$, $m$ and $s$ where $g$ is the proposition “The
>      gold path brings you to the center”, and similarly for $m$ and $s$. Express
>      the three statements made by the centaurs as compound propositions
>      using $g$, $m$ and $s$. Call these $C_1$, $C_2$ and $C_3$ respectively.
> 2. Draw the truth table for the proposition $C_1 \land C_2 \land C_3$.
> 3. Which path should you choose to ensure that you will find the treasure?

**My attempt**

I drew up a truth table and I think the answer is supposed to be that just one of $g$ or $m$ or $s$ is supposed to be true if the negations of $c_1$,$c_2$,$c_3$ are all true. But I'm getting multiple answers. Could you please tell me if I'm doing something wrong [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y8e-srySJ2rKaR3BEi02UXeMsBCqemF52jZHgqn08Ys/edit?usp=sharing)?

Comment: Negations are correct and the t-t is correct (it seems to me, upon two reading...).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks!  But this leaves me a little confused. 

The overall question asks which path will ensure I get taken to the center? I'm not sure how to get there from my truth table. I thought only one version of ¬c1^¬c2^¬c3 would be all true but now there are three..
How do I know which one of these versions reflects the correct path to take?

Sorry if this is a really basic question, learning this from scratch ><

PS> I've updated the question on the doc for the whole riddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\neg c_1 \equiv (¬g)∨(s∧¬m)$, $\neg c_2 \equiv g∨s$ and $\neg c_3 \equiv (¬ g)∨m$.

In this case we just need to note that:
$$\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
g & m & s & (\neg c_1) \land (\neg c_2) \land (\neg c_3) \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0  \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{0} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{1} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

This means that the stone path is the correct path that leads you to the center.

Have a good treasure!

Comment: @B Bentzen 
Thanks for your help. Could I ask you one thing? The original question has g,m,s as potential paths to the center of a city. And then it asks which one takes you to the center based on the statements. So now three sets of ¬c1^¬c2^¬c3 are all true...How do I determine which is the right path from there?
I've updated the full question onto the doc
Thank you!

Comment: Could you also explain what you meant by 

"By the way note that the negated speech of the three guards are not inconsistent themselves"

Unfortunately, I hadn't got it already :(

Comment: @B Bentzen Hmmmm I don't quite see the difference in m. 
1st truth: g=t, m=t, s=t
2nd truth: g=f, m=f, s=t
3rd truth: g=f, m=t, s=t
I get the feeling that you mean m is supposed to always be true whereas g and s might have a false in one of the combinations...is that what you mean? or is there something else more special about m that I'm missing :(

Comment: Thank you. So if none of them have all true then is it possible that there is no path you should choose to ensure the treasure is found?

Comment: ahhhh, I made a mistake. I said 
C1 = g∧(m⇒s)
but it should have been
C1 = g∧(s⇒m)
derp.........

Comment: @hchenn I see you've got the answer for your problem: the stone path is the right one. That was just a simple matter of attention.

Comment: haha thanks mate! +rep for you!

Comment: @hchenn Maybe this could be helpful: next time you can format you truth-tables using the [array environment](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Array_(LaTeX_environment)).

Comment: Fascinating! Yeah, I've been wondering how to write things that look like equations. Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 1):

The last column of the truth table should also be true, since ¬g is true, making the statement ¬g∨(s∧¬m) true.

Comment: oh no! then once again there is more than one answer :"(

Comment: oh wait, but s is ALWAYS true whereas m isn't

Answer (score 0):

Would ¬c3 answer be "and" or "or"?

"(¬g) ∧ m" or "(¬g) ∨ m"

Follow the gold path and you’ll reach the center, follow the marble path and you will be lost.”

Seems to me like an "or" which would be negated to an "and" using De Morgans Laws?

Comment: "not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"
so g becomes not g, and becomes or, not m becomes m

Comment: So the statement "Follow the gold path and you’ll reach the center, follow the marble path and you will be lost." is an "and" to begin with before you decide the centaur is lying

Comment: @hchenn its the english part of that that is confusing

Comment: So you assume the centaur isn't lying to begin with and interpret it as and. Then you negate the whole statement